# Need help wiring ceiling fan wall control to 3way switch

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I am installing a parrot uncle ceiling fan F3504A that came with a wall control (remote). The directions are unclear
Basic wiring to ceiling fan with light white to neutral and blue black to hot.

- The wall control says connect: ac to black (hot),
- “light L” on fan to “for light L” on wall control,
  and
- “Fan L” on fan to “for fan L” on wall control

but there is no wires from fan to wall switch for that. The neutral and blue on wall control is looped into relay I need help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The instructions are unclear and so is your recitation of them. Please [edit] your post to include some formatting (a `*` makes a bulleted list out of steps), the _exact_ make/model of the fan and maybe even clear, focused pictures of the instruction page and the box(es) you're attempting to wire these in to. That will help immensely for those trying to help you.

Comment: Was there only a light fixture where you want to install this fan/light combo? Was there a single switch at the switch box you want to place this combined fan/light wall switch?

Comment: It may be that this new wall switch will only work if you have separate wires for separate hots to the fan and the light. It may be that this wall switch is not a wireless transmitter to a receiver/electronic switch in the fan, and if so it will require separate hot wires (usu a black and a red) from the switch box to the ceiling box.,m

Comment: Was the original switch in the box you want to put this fan/light switch a "3-way" switch, and were there two such switches in separate boxes that controlled a single light by toggling so that flipping either switch would switch the light from on to off or off to on?

Comment: Are you wedded to this particular fan control?

Comment: Yes it’s an old house and had old light fixture only. There are 3way switches to front and back of kitchen..... if the original switch is off the other switch will not have power.    In the ceiling there is only hot and neutral that’s it. By reading the directions I assume I need to run a line to the fixture in order to separate the light control from fan

Comment: They are able to toggle light as long as the original switch is on.  I’m not the concerned about their switch configuration bc I want to wire ceiling fan to original switch

Comment: If I have to run a wire it probably would be better and easier to install an universal remote